# How to redirect a users when they visit to the login page?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I am following the microsoft's offical webforms tutorial. In this tutorial they explain how to redirect a users if they provide valid credentials or redirect them to the login page when they are not logged in and try to visit a protected page. However, what if the user is already logged in- the forms authentication ticket has been stored and visits the login page. How do I access the forms authentication ticket from there and redirect the user to the defualt page?

link to the tutorial
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the login page, you check if is all ready Authenticated and you just redirect him as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // if is already logged in
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // redirect to home page
            Response.Redirect("/");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the difference between Request.IsAuthenticated and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ?